# Logoff account in an old work computer?

Tags: teamviewer

I have an account in Teamviewer where all my computers are in my account.
In my last job I've also logged in into that account and added the work computer.

but I've left the work since then and I'm afraid that i'm still logged in in the teamviewer account at the work's computer.

How can I log off my TV account in my work , remotely ?

I'm not allowed to connect to the computer work anymore since I don't work there anymore.

**Question**
How can I log off the connected TV account at my work ?

Comment: If you log into your account from a browser, you can see all the machines associated with the account. Under `Properties` there is the option to delete. However, if you connected direct using the IDs, individual passwords may still be held, so you should change the direct passwords on all the machines on the account.

Comment: @AFH I don't think I was understood. I;m afraid that i'm still logged in there and they can connect to my other computers (which all computers have quick connect feature on) BTW I think I got it. I've changed the password in web , and instantly i was logged out from the EXE file. ( also was logged out from another pc which had my credentials as logged in).

Comment: I assumed that the work computer would be restarted before long, but changing the account password is of course recommended.

Comment: AFH is correct. Change the account password and remove the pc from the TeamViewer web is what you need to do.

Comment: TeamViewer also works with trusted devices. You have to add a pc to a trusted device every time you log in. You can also remove the device from that list if you can Identify it.Then you don't need to change the password.